# What does "I'm all the wiser" means?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of this phrase?

> I'm all the wiser for the many wrongs I've done.

This is from Armin Van Buuren's *Take A Moment* song.

> Wise - having or showing experience, knowledge, and good judgment.
>
> Wiser - adjective.

Particularly, I'm confused with the form *I'm all the wiser* — I've never heard someone saying *I'm all the [something]*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an intensifier, "all the" carries the same meaning as "even" when placed in front of a comparative adjective. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all#English

Another example:

"I love you all the more for your imperfections."

Answer (score 2):

I knew the term "I'm none the wiser." Before which means somebody explained something to you or answered your question but you did not learn anything.

Maybe the artist just plays off of this more common expression by exchanging the none for the all. So "I'm all the wiser." Has the same connotation of none the wiser. Which would be I wasted my time, but this way you might have wasted your time but are also wiser. Because you learned something. Or gained experience.

Comment: Judge to Counsel "I'm afraid I'm none the wiser for your speech, Mr Smith." Counsel "Possibly not, my lord, but better informed."