# When is the "all" in "all right" an intensifier?

Tags: adverbs, linguistics, intensifying-adverbs

I'm currently analysing intensifiers/amplifiers, and I have some trouble with the word "all". If used as in "I'm all fine, thanks", it's an intensifier, indicating the extent in which I'm fine (completely, utterly). How would one classify it if instead I'm saying "Just to make sure, all right"? Would that differ from the usage "All right, let's go!"?

I guess I'm just unsure how idiomatic expressions fit into this category.
Thanks for helping me out here :)

Comment: Perhaps the ['all the wiser/better/happier ...' strings](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155772/what-does-im-all-the-wiser-means/155776#155776) are also of interest to you.

Comment: The string 'all right' is used in various ways, sometimes (at least) best interpreted as unary usages, as illustrated by the single-word version (and synonym OK) nowadays widely accepted in certain contexts. As Crystal says, some strings are best considered to be single lexemes. // The intensifier usage is often more idiomatic in the US; In 'Sherlock', SH says '"Aren't you all better?!" to an American spy he previously clobbered. Though'all done in', listed as an idiom (fixed expression employing metaphor) by the Free Dictionary, is not outlandish to British ears.

Comment: I guess this question is really about the origin of [all right, adverb, sense 2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all%20right) "used interjectionally especially to express agreement or resignation or to indicate the resumption of a discussion" because as an idiom the separate parts no longer function separately, any more than "al" functions separately when you spell it "alright" (which according to [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/all-right-or-alright-which-is-correct) is a variant spelling and does not have a separate meaning).

Comment: Though 'all' = 'completely/extremely' in its intensifier usage, its distribution is very different from (and much smaller than) that of these other modifiers-of-adverbs/adjectives. 'It is extremely cold' / 'She was completely baffled' / He lived all alone in a shack in the forest.' 'Very' is the commonest intensifier, and not even it works everywhere.

Comment: The 'independent word' approach also gets blurred when one considers examples (definitely containing intensification) such as 'all-important', 'all-powerful',  'all-singing, all-dancing'. I'd class 'all-inclusive' (all = everything) and 'all-terrain' (all = every kind of) etc  differently.

Comment: I think you mean to use *I'm all right, thanks* in your example. No one says *I'm all fine, thanks*.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard anyone say *I'm all fine* to mean *I'm alright* (*I'm all right* in British and older orthography), but let that one pass.

According to the full Oxford English Dictionary, the first recorded use of ***all** right* defined as *Used as an **intensifier** at the end of a sentence or clause: **certainly, indeed*** was...

> G. Chaucer *Troilus & Criseyde* (1385)
> *Criseyde was þis lady name **al right***.

---

For completeness, [here's a chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Alright%20he%2CAll%20right%20he&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=10) showing that *American* orthography has only recently shifted in favour of the one-word form...

[image]

...but Brits [mostly still write the two-word form.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Alright%20he%2CAll%20right%20he&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=10)

Comment: Yes and further, if 'all right' uses an intensifier, presumably there is a less intense form, 'right.' Who recognises 'right' without 'all'?

Comment: *Yeah, **right**!*